# Width clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX) not behaving same as max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX)) where VAL = 100% and MIN/MAX are absolute values

Tags: css, firefox, clamp

### Context

I interpret **clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)** to mean: *Aim for VAL unless it exceeds MAX or falls below MIN.*

When applied to **WIDTH of text**, my understanding is that the text element will take 100% of the container width unless it falls below MIN or exceeds MAX.

According to Mozilla,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

> clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX) is resolved as max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX))

In Firefox 87, the two behave differently.

The clamp VAL 100% ignores the MIN **and** MAX values, whereas it behaves as expected in max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX)).

---

### Here is an example at wide width:

[image]

---

### Headscratching

I'm not sure if this is a bug in FF 87 I should report or if there is something I'm not understanding about how clamp works. Seems to work OK in Chrome 89.

Comment: it seems you discovered a bug